# Derive the $d=1$ form of the Wasserstein distance

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, optimal-transport, wasserstein

**QUESTION**

**Given**
[image]

**How to pass from the general definition of the Wasserstein distance (let's call it Equation (1)):**
[image]
**to the closed forms with d=1, here below (let's call them Equation (2) and Equation(3))?**
[image]
[image]

**Where can I find the details to pass from Equation (1) to Equations (2) and (3)?**

**Notes:**

- It looks like you need to know notions from "Optimal transport" (for example from [Villani, C., (2008) Optimal transport, old and new](https://cedricvillani.org/sites/dev/files/old_images/2012/08/preprint-1.pdf)), "measure theory" (i.e. Lebesgue measure and Lebesgue integration) and, maybe, from "multivariate statistics" (?).
- It looks like that from Equation (1), where there are a "transport plan" a.k.a. joint distributions "J", with the corresponding marginal distributions "P" and "Q", and a Lp-norm among "x" and "y", you jump to Equation (2) and (3) where you have, respectively, inverse-CDFs, i.e. "F^{-1}" and "G^{-1}" and the Lp-norm among "X" and "Y". **How?**